# Animate SVG with CSS: first the stroke, then the fill

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm completely new to animating SVGs with CSS (from what I've been reading, JS might also be needed to get the total path length) and need to achieve the following effect: http://gph.is/2iZZ3Hw

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;stroke:#FEC558;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256;}
    .st1{fill:#FFC656;}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z"/>
    <g>
        <polygon class="st1" points="14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7 
    32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2   "/>
        <polygon class="st1" points="19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 
    15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7     "/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ explains how to animate SVG strokes. And yes, JS is needed to calculate the path lengths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### SVG animation

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:none;stroke:#FEC558;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:22.9256;}
    .st1{fill:#FFC656;}
</style>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
         
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33363D"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5B5D5A"/>
</lineargradient>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>

<path id="circle" class="st0" stroke-dashoffset="138" stroke-dasharray="138" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z">
<animate id="an_circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="138;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
</path>
    <g stroke-width="0.5">
       <path id="trap" class="st1" stroke-dashoffset="60" stroke-dasharray="60" style="fill:none; stroke:#FEC558;" d="M14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7  32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2z">
        <animate id="an_trap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="60;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
        <animate id="fill_trap" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="an_circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
        <path id="triangle" class="st1" stroke-dashoffset="35" stroke-dasharray="35" style="fill:none; stroke:#FEC558;"  d="M19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7">
        
        <animate id="an_triangle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_trap.end" values="35;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
          <animate id="fill_triangle" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  begin="fill_trap.end-0.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

- Determine the length of objects using JS

```
    <script>
             function TotalLength(){
              var path = document.querySelector('#circle');
            var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
            alert("path length - " + len);
            };
      </script>
```

**Path length:**

for circle - `138px`

for trapezium - `60px`

for triangle - `35px`

- Command for drawing animation of objects

```
<animate id="an_circle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="138;0" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

```
  <animate id="an_trap" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     values="60;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

```
<animate id="an_triangle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
   begin="an_trap.end" values="35;0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

- The animation of drawing a triangle will begin when the animation of
  drawing of a trapezoid

`begin="an_trap.end"`

- Animation fill color trapezium will begin when the animation is
  finished drawing a circle

```
<animate id="fill_trap" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  
    begin="an_circle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

- An animation of the color filling of the triangle will begin when the
  fill animation of the trapezium ends

```
    <animate id="fill_triangle" attributeName="fill" values="#33363D;#FEC558"  
       begin="fill_trap.end-0.5s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. I'm going to choose this as the answer. What if I don't want to modify the SVG code? Can I do this with CSS3 or JS alone? Thanks again!

Comment: @CristianC Yes. I can replace the Smill of SVG by CSS animation. I will try to make this answer

Answer (score 2):

### CSS solution

- An animation for drawing shape outlines is implemented using CSS
  rules:

*for the circle*

```
.circle {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#FEC558;
    stroke-dashoffset:138.5;
    stroke-dasharray:138.5;
    animation: circle_stroke 2s ease-in forwards;
        } 

    @keyframes circle_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 138.5;
    }
    100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
```

- Animating the trapezium contour drawing and filling it with color

code below

```
.trap {
    stroke-dashoffset:60;
    stroke-dasharray:60;
        animation:trap_stroke 2s ease-in-out forwards,  trap_fill  ease-in 3s forwards;

    }

    @keyframes trap_stroke {
    0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60.5;
    }

      100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }  

    @keyframes trap_fill {
    0% {
    fill: none;
    }

      100% {
    fill: #FEC558;
      }
    }
```

*Full animation code*

```css
 .trap, .triangle {
   stroke:#FEC558;
   stroke-width:0.5;
 fill:none;
   }
 
 .circle {
 fill:none;
 stroke:#FEC558;
 stroke-dashoffset:138.5;
 stroke-dasharray:138.5;
 animation: circle_stroke 2s ease-in forwards;
  } 
 
 @keyframes circle_stroke {
 0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 138.5;
 }
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }
 

 
 
 .trap {
 stroke-dashoffset:60;
 stroke-dasharray:60;
  animation:trap_stroke 2s ease-in-out forwards,  trap_fill  ease-in 3s forwards;
 
 }
 
 @keyframes trap_stroke {
 0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 60.5;
 }
    
   100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }  
 
 @keyframes trap_fill {
 0% {
    fill: none;
 }
    
   100% {
    fill: #FEC558;
   }
 }  


 .triangle {
 stroke-dashoffset:35.5;
 stroke-dasharray:35.5;
 
 animation: triangle_stroke 1s ease-in-out forwards, triangle_fill 3.5s ease-in forwards;
 }  
 
 @keyframes triangle_stroke {
 0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 35.5;
 }
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
   }
 }  
 
 @keyframes triangle_fill {
 0% {
    fill: none;
 }
 100% {
    fill: #FEC558;;
   }
 }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 47.4 47.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 47.4 47.7;" xml:space="preserve">  

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" >
         
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#33363D"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#5B5D5A"/>
</lineargradient>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)"/>

<path class="circle" d="M23.7,45.8c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-12.1-9.9-22-22-22c-12.1,0-22,9.9-22,22C1.7,35.9,11.6,45.8,23.7,45.8z"/>

    
       <path class="trap"    d="M14.1,17.9 14.1,20.2 14.1,22.2 14.1,23.4 14.1,24.7 14.1,27.6 32.7,35.2 32.7,32.5 32.7,30.7  32.7,29.7 32.7,28.5 32.7,25.2z" />
          
        <path class="triangle"   d="M19.2,18.7 24.3,20.6 27.5,21.9 27.5,21.2 27.5,19.4 27.5,17.5 27.5,16.3 27.5,15.2 27.5,12.5 15.5,17.2 19.2,18.7"/>
 

</svg>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/q3a1kzyu/)

**UPD**

Works in all modern browsers, except IE

"[IE10 and IE11 do not support CSS keyframe blocks inside media queries](https://caniuse.com/#search=animation)."

(see the "Known Issues")